# Reset apple id password immediately

Tags: iphone, icloud, security, apple-id, password

I just upgraded IOS and I needed to enter icloud password during upgrade and I can't remember my apple ID password and followed password reset page - https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid

After few crazy overlapping text in captcha retries I reached the final page where it says I'll receive email or text after 24 hours.

After more than 12 hours I received email that says "An account recovery request was made for your Apple ID" and I'll receive another text or phone call to reset password on "8 October 2017 at 08:50:09 GMT+8" and today is 25th September.

Does everyone really need to wait that long or am I not using the right forgot password page?

Comment: (Not an answer, just my similar experience.)  I have also tried this method, received a similar email, waited to be contacted, and was not further contacted.  Apple customer service was unable to help me over the phone, was not able to take any action on my previous account recovery request, and wanted me to come to one of their store locations for help.

Comment: If you really have forgotten things, the last resort mechanism is very slow.  It may take weeks before you get access again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which device you are using. So I list some methods to reset your Apple ID.

On iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch

1. You need to have iOS 10 or newer.
2. Select "Settings".
3. Select your account name, then Password & Security, and finally Change Password.
4. For iOS 10.2 or older iOS, it's the same but first, you must select "iCloud".

On Mac

1. Open the Apple menu, then "System Preferences", then click "iCloud".
2. Select "Account Details".
3. Click "Forgot Apple ID or password".
4. Click "Security", then "Reset Password". Before you can change your Apple ID password, you'll be asked to enter the password for your Mac.

Comment: THANK YOU for the "On Mac" section.  I have not found this method of resetting a forgotten password anywhere else.  Even tried calling Apple support and they wanted me to come in to one of their locations.  (I have no other apple products.)  Note: In my case, on High Sierra 10.13.6, step #3 "Forgot Apple ID or password" does not appear as an option.  Proceeded fine to step 4.